# PyCharm: independent/related projects configurations

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I just installed PyCharm in my Mac Sierra. I would like to make sure all my future projects are properly configured using virtualenv. I created Test3 after Test2:

[image]

Then in the Open Project select, if I choose "Add to currently opened projects", does this mean the Test3 is a sub-project of Test2? Or they are still independent projects?

Also, in the future, can I still open Test3 without opening Test2? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Multiple Project Implementation,

- The first project you have opened is considered the primary project,
  and it's always displayed on top in the project view.
- Opening the primary project (via Open Directory or Reopen actions)
  loads it together with the attached projects.
- A project can be detached from the primary project using the "Detach
  Project" action in the context menu. The primary project cannot be
  detached. When you create a new project, you also have the option to
  attach it to the currently opened one.
- Attached projects are added as dependencies to the primary one. In
  PyCharm, it means that symbols from attached projects are visible
  from the primary one, but not vice versa.

Source: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Multiple+Projects+Implementation

Edit: Detaching the Project can be done by right clicking on the project and selecting the "Remove from the Project" option on context menu or pressing delete key.

[image]

Comment: **Right click on the project you want to detach on the project tool window -> Select Remove from the project view** and it will ask you if you want to detach the project